# Why does the dex methods count add 3 when I add one method?

Tags: android-proguard, android-multidex

I add a method

```
public static void cancelAll(RequestQueue queue,@NonNull final Object tag){
        queue.cancelAll(new RequestQueue.RequestFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(Request<?> request) {

                Object oldTag = request.getTag();
                if(tag == null || oldTag == null){
                    return false;
                }
                if(oldTag instanceof Integer && tag instanceof Integer){
                    return (int)oldTag == (int)tag;
                }else if(oldTag instanceof String && tag instanceof String){
                    return ((String) tag).equalsIgnoreCase((String)oldTag);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

And the dex method count add 3.

I think they are cancelAll and apply.Where is the third?

BuildType is release.And I use proguard.

It's same when I set buildType to debug.

Answer (score 0):

The dex method count that you are referring to specifies the total number of methods that were *referenced* within a single dex, not only the *declared* ones!
Therefore your question cannot be easily answered.

Why not just dump all the method names using a tool such as [dextra](http://newandroidbook.com/tools/dextra.html) with and without this method and then diff the outputs?
For example:

```
./dextra -M classes.dex
```

will output all the referenced method_ids list in following format:

```
Method (0): <init>  Access Flags: 0x0    Params: () Returns: V
Method (1): attachBaseContext   Access Flags: 0x0    Params: (Landroid/content/Context;)    Returns: V
Method (2): getClassLoader  Access Flags: 0x0    Params: () Returns: Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
...
```

Comment: I will have a try when I' m free.